# Forbidden 403 You don't have permission to access this resource. (mod_wsgi, wamp, apache2.4, django) on windows

Tags: django, windows, apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

i have installed everything properly and gone through all solutions related to this subject but still error remains, I'm new to Django and i would really appreciate your help

I get this error in my error log file:

[Fri Feb 14 21:52:16.916422 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 4288:tid 1252] [client ::1:51391] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: E:/AppSource/eCommerce/src/ecommerce/wsgi_windows.py

and when i try to reach 127.0.0.1:80 i get: Forbidden 403

and this is my wsgi_windows.py configuration:

```
activate_this = 'CE:/AppSource/eCommerce/Scripts/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))
import os
import sys
import site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
site.addsitedir("C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages")
sys.path.append('E:/AppSource/eCommerce') 
sys.path.append('E:/AppSource/eCommerce/src')
sys.path.append('E:/AppSource/eCommerce/src/ecommerce')  
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ecommerce.settings' 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecommerce.settings")  
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and this is hhtpd-vhosts.conf configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost 
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "E:/appSource/eCommerce/eCommerce.error.log"
    CustomLog "E:/appSource/eCommerce/eCommerce.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "E:/appSource/eCommerce/src/ecommerce/wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory "E:/appSource/eCommerc/src/ecommerce/">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
 Alias /static "E:/appSource/eCommerce/static_cdn/static_root"

    <Directory "E:/appSource/eCommerce/static_cdn/static_root">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  

    Alias /media "E:/appSource/eCommerce/static_cdn/media_root"
    <Directory "E:/appSource/eCommerce/static_cdn/media_root">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i have tried everything that i know 
Please help to solve this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve your goal is to change the port number of apache and start the apache again.

Comment: i changed the port and reached to apache with some errors about index file error and didn't get the 403 error 
but when i try to reach server from outside of network with its ip still get the same 403 error